# Keep getting 404 errors in Bottle

Tags: python, python-3.6, bottle

I am trying to run examples presented on this [website](http://zetcode.com/python/bottle/)

My code is this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from bottle import route, run

@route('/cars')
def getcars():

    cars = [ {'name': 'Audi', 'price': 52642},
        {'name': 'Mercedes', 'price': 57127},
        {'name': 'Skoda', 'price': 9000},
        {'name': 'Volvo', 'price': 29000},
        {'name': 'Bentley', 'price': 350000},
        {'name': 'Citroen', 'price': 21000},
        {'name': 'Hummer', 'price': 41400},
        {'name': 'Volkswagen', 'price': 21600} ]

    return dict(data=cars)


run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

When I run python run.py, and log on to http://localhost:8080/cars. I get the 404 errors. When I run the following example, I get the same 404 errors

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from bottle import route, run

@route('/message')
def hello():
    return "Today is a beautiful day"  

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This works fine with python3.6.2

Comment: I am using 3.7 actually

Comment: It works on 3.7 too. Are you sure (sorry) to write /cars in the url end? (maybe you click the link in the console that doesn't have it). What does the console print?

Comment: I used the integrated terminal in vs code. It did not work. It works when I use a normal terminal window in Win 10

Comment: Maybe it's calling a different python version without bottle installed...

Comment: no it is the same. but there is a great delay when changing code

Answer (score 0):

I have python2.7. I have tried the same , I am getting correct output

```
{"data": [{"price": 52642, "name": "Audi"}, {"price": 57127, "name": "Mercedes"}, {"price": 9000, "name": "Skoda"}, {"price": 29000, "name": "Volvo"}, {"price": 350000, "name": "Bentley"}, {"price": 21000, "name": "Citroen"}, {"price": 41400, "name": "Hummer"}, {"price": 21600, "name": "Volkswagen"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use @get and @post instead of just @route.